# Problemas dentro del if

Tags: condiciones, else

Saludos vengo empezando en el mundo de  la progracion espero me ayuden.
Lo que pasa es que al momento de el usuario introducir un numero diferente a 1 o 2 el menu vuelve a aparecer para reingresar el numero el problema es que si el numero es igual a 1 o 2 el munu aparece igualmente y quisiera lograr que el menu siga pareciendo hasta que introduzca un numero valido (1 o 2) cosa que no he logrado

```
    public static class Menu
    {

        public static void opciones() throws IOException
        {
            BufferedReader reader = 
               new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.print("Buscaminas\n");

            System.out.print("1.Jugar\n");               
            System.out.print("2.Puntuacion\n ");
            System.out.print("Elige una opción:  ");        
            String op = reader.readLine();
            jugar ju = new jugar();
            if(op!="1" && op!="2"+"\n"){
                    System.out.print("Digitaste algo incorrecto: "+"\n");
                    System.out.print("1.Jugar\n");               
                    System.out.print("2.Puntuacion\n ");
                    System.out.print("Elige una opción: ");
                    op=reader.readLine();
            }else{
                    System.out.print("Digitaste algo incorrecto: "+"\n");
                    System.out.print("1.Jugar\n");               
                    System.out.print("2.Puntuacion\n ");
                    System.out.print("Elige una opción: ");
                    op=reader.readLine();






                    }
            switch (op)
            {
                case "1":

                    System.out.print("1.- Facil\n");
                    System.out.print("2.- Intermedio\n ");
                    System.out.print("Elige una opción:");
                    String op1 = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Necesitas usar una estructura `while`

Comment: @Alfabravo gracias lo implemente pero hace un bucle infinito

Comment: Entonces el problema no es el while sino la condición que lo ejecuta. Edita la pregunta indicando cómo intentaste usarlo

Answer (score 0):

tu estás intentando hacer un menu que siempre reaparezca si la opción es incorrecta. Para esto te recomiendo que utilices un bucle while, en caso de que la condición no se cumpla (en este caso, el input sea distinto de 1 ó 2), se vuelve a ejecutar.

```java
String op = "";
while (!op.equals("1") || !op.equals("2"))
{
  /* mostrar las opciones del menu */
  op = reader.readLine();
}
```

En cuanto a comparar los resultados de la variable `op`, te recomiendo que utilices el método `.equals()`, (que devuelve verdadero, si el objeto equivale al argumento del método) ya que, sólo va a comparar lo "escrito". Te recomiendo que leas este [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/what-is-the-difference-between-and-equals-in-java).

Comment: gracias pero dice que la String op; no esta inicializada

Comment: Si, disculpa. Olvidé inicializarlo, puedes iniciarlo como un String vacío. Además, las condiciones estaba puestas como ```op.equals("1")```, lo que quería decir que si op equivale a "1", el bucle debe ejecutarse. Lo cual es erróneo. La condición debería ser opuesta, por eso le corregí, y le añadí una negación a las condiciones. Espero haberte ayudado.